# regex to find each match

Tags: python, regex

Using the following HTML:

```
    <!-- DW6 --><!-- kelly 10-28-16 the white box welcome email -->
    <!-- e2ma-autonomous-cv -->
    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
     <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
       <o:AllowPNG/>
       <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
     </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml><![endif] -->
    <!--[if !mso]><!-- --><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><!--<![endif]-->
<style>
h1 {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000
}
h2 {
    font-family: "Lato", "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase
}
h3 {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    font-style: italic
}
h4 {
    font-family: "Lato", "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000
}
.e2ma-content-block p, .e2ma-combo-block p, .e2ma-combo-content p, .e2ma-content-block li, .e2ma-combo-block li, .e2ma-combo-content li {
    font-family: "Lato", "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000
}
#template_container a, .link {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: underline
}
blockquote {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    font-style: italic
}
blockquote p {
    margin-bottom: 0
}
.editable_image img {
    display: block;
    border: 0
}
.e2ma-unsubscribe {
    padding-bottom: 10px
}
.business_rsvp {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 10px
}
[style*="Lato"] {
    font-family: "Lato", Arial, sans-serif !important
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none
}
*[class].e2ma-content-block p, *[class].e2ma-combo-block p, *[class].e2ma-combo-content p, *[class].e2ma-content-block li, *[class].e2ma-combo-block li, *[class].e2ma-combo-content li {
    font-size: 15px !important
}
*[class].e2ma-holder table, *[class].e2ma-holder table td {
    display: table !important;
    float: none !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important
}
*[class].e2ma-single-column-layout table {
    float: none !important;
    margin: 0 auto
}
*[class].e2ma-unsubscribe span {
    font-size: 12px !important
}
*[class].business_rsvp {
    font-size: 12px !important
}
*[class].social-sharing {
    text-align: center !important;
    padding-bottom: 10px
}
*[class].e2ma-layout-column-content img, *[class].e2ma-single-column-layout img, *[class].e2ma-layout-column-sidebar img, *[class].e2ma-layout-column-sidebar-2 img, *[class].e2ma-layout-column-sidebar-3 img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto
}
*[class].footer-social img {
    width: 44px !important;
    height: 43px !important;
    margin: 0 auto
}
*[class].share-block {
    text-align: center !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important
}
*[class].footer-text {
    text-align: center !important
}
*[class].mobile-width {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px
}
*[class].mobile-width-nopad {
    width: 100% !important
}
*[class].stack, *[class].e2ma-layout-column-content, *[class].e2ma-layout-column-sidebar, *[class].e2ma-layout-column-sidebar-2, *[class].e2ma-layout-column-sidebar-3 {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100% !important
}
*[class].hide {
    display: none !important
}
*[class].center, *[class].center img {
    text-align: center !important;
    margin: 0 auto
}
*[class].scale img, *[class].editable_image img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto
}
*[class].addpad {
    padding: 10px !important
}
*[class].addpad-top {
    padding-top: 10px !important
}
*[class].sanpad {
    padding: 0 !important
}
*[class].sanborder {
    border: none !important
}
*[class].nav212 {
    width: 212 px !important;
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important
}
}
</style>
```

And the following python regex:

```
conditional_search = r"(<!--.*\[if.*\]>.*<!--.*\n*.*endif\]-->)"
it = re.finditer(conditional_search, html, flags=re.DOTALL)
print([tuple(i.groups()) for i in it])
```

The ouput from `print` is matching everything from `<!-- DW6 -->` to the end of the `</style>` tag. I am just trying to find each `<!--if` HTML comment block (including the double `<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->`).

Comment: have you tried beautifulsoup?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't like this particular markup: `<!--[if !mso]><!-- --><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><!--<![endif]-->`... So I am using regex to try to shift these kind of tags separate before running my HTML through BeautifulSoup

Comment: Which parsers have you tried with BeautifulSoup?  Some parsers work better than others for some situations.

Comment: I've tried `html5lib` and `html.parser`. The idea is to gather these sort of HTML comment blocks (that include links, styles, etc) and add them to the head tag in the HTML markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot.  Basically I'm just ripping out all the carriage returns (maybe you want to keep them?) and adjusted the regex a bit.  Just leave a comment if the regex is unclear, I *think* it's pretty straight forward.  If I'm understanding what you are looking for this should do the trick.  Here is my whole test script:

```
import re

textblock = '''
 <!-- DW6 --><!-- kelly 10-28-16 the white box welcome email -->
    <!-- e2ma-autonomous-cv -->
    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
     <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
       <o:AllowPNG/>
       <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
     </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml><![endif] -->
    <!--[if !mso]><!-- --><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><!--<![endif]-->
<style>
h1 {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000
}
h2 {
    font-family: "Lato", "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase
}
h3 {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    font-style: italic
}
h4 {
    font-family: "Lato", "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000
}
.e2ma-content-block p, .e2ma-combo-block p, .e2ma-combo-content p, .e2ma-content-block li, .e2ma-combo-block li, .e2ma-combo-content li {
    font-family: "Lato", "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000
}
#template_container a, .link {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: underline
}
blockquote {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    font-style: italic
}
blockquote p {
    margin-bottom: 0
}
.editable_image img {
    display: block;
    border: 0
}
.e2ma-unsubscribe {
    padding-bottom: 10px
}
.business_rsvp {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 10px
}
[style*="Lato"] {
    font-family: "Lato", Arial, sans-serif !important
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none
}
*[class].e2ma-content-block p, *[class].e2ma-combo-block p, *[class].e2ma-combo-content p, *[class].e2ma-content-block li, *[class].e2ma-combo-block li, *[class].e2ma-combo-content li {
    font-size: 15px !important
}
*[class].e2ma-holder table, *[class].e2ma-holder table td {
    display: table !important;
    float: none !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important
}
*[class].e2ma-single-column-layout table {
    float: none !important;
    margin: 0 auto
}
*[class].e2ma-unsubscribe span {
    font-size: 12px !important
}
*[class].business_rsvp {
    font-size: 12px !important
}
*[class].social-sharing {
    text-align: center !important;
    padding-bottom: 10px
}
*[class].e2ma-layout-column-content img, *[class].e2ma-single-column-layout img, *[class].e2ma-layout-column-sidebar img, *[class].e2ma-layout-column-sidebar-2 img, *[class].e2ma-layout-column-sidebar-3 img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto
}
*[class].footer-social img {
    width: 44px !important;
    height: 43px !important;
    margin: 0 auto
}
*[class].share-block {
    text-align: center !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important
}
*[class].footer-text {
    text-align: center !important
}
*[class].mobile-width {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px
}
*[class].mobile-width-nopad {
    width: 100% !important
}
*[class].stack, *[class].e2ma-layout-column-content, *[class].e2ma-layout-column-sidebar, *[class].e2ma-layout-column-sidebar-2, *[class].e2ma-layout-column-sidebar-3 {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100% !important
}
*[class].hide {
    display: none !important
}
*[class].center, *[class].center img {
    text-align: center !important;
    margin: 0 auto
}
*[class].scale img, *[class].editable_image img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto
}
*[class].addpad {
    padding: 10px !important
}
*[class].addpad-top {
    padding-top: 10px !important
}
*[class].sanpad {
    padding: 0 !important
}
*[class].sanborder {
    border: none !important
}
*[class].nav212 {
    width: 212 px !important;
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important
}
}
</style>
'''

text = re.sub("\n", " ", textblock)
conditional_search = "<!--\[if[^\]]+\]>(.*?)<!\[endif\]"
it = re.findall(conditional_search, text)
for i in it:
    print (i)
    print ("how now brown cow")
```

Comment: `[('<xml>  <o:OfficeDocumentSettings> <o:AllowPNG/>    <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch> </o:OfficeDocumentSettings> </xml><![endif] --> <!--[if !mso]><!-- --><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><!--',), ('   <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:700px;height:361px;">     <v:fill type="tile" src="https://e2ma-templates.s3.amazonaws.com/1780048/images/templates/bgimage_02.jpg" color="#ffffff" ></v:fill>   <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">   ',), ('     </v:textbox>   </v:rect>   ',)]`

Comment: Thats the tuple I am seeing with the regex

Comment: whooops, I'll take a look

Comment: By mistake I updated your question with my answer, hopefully somebody can just fix that!  Anyways.. there is an update to the regex.  Bonus Brown Cow thrown in there.